# How to obtain the absolute value of numbers?

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers that looks like the one below:

```
[2, 3, -3, -2]
```

How can I obtain a list of values that contain the absolute value of every value in the above list? In this case it would be:

```
[2, 3, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

1. You can use [`abs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#abs) and [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) functions like this

   ```
   myList = [2,3,-3,-2]
   print map(abs, myList)
   ```

   **Output**

   ```
   [2, 3, 3, 2]
   ```
2. Or you can use list comprehension like this

   ```
   [abs(number) for number in myList]
   ```
3. Or you can use list comprehension and a simple if else condition like this

   ```
   [-number if number < 0 else number for number in myList]
   ```

Answer (score 2):

A [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) would also work:

```
>>> lst = [2,3,-3,-2]
>>> [abs(x) for x in lst]
[2, 3, 3, 2]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

`[ abs(x) for x in list ]` would do it.